# Scala batch jobs in parallel

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a function in Scala which does batch work.  It's designed to be self synchronizing, so that you can run 1 instance of it or 1000, on one machine or a cluster, and it will synchronize using external middleware.

For performance, I'd like one JVM to run the function in multiple threads.  (I want this done in the same JVM to conserve RAM).  Ideally, the code should look something like:

```
execInParallel(9, myBatchFunction) // Starts 9 threads and invokes myBatchFunction() in each one
```

What is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Non - blocking version:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent._
import collection.JavaConverters._

def execInParallel[T](numberThreads: Int, body: => T): util.List[Future[T]] = {
  val javaExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberThreads) // fixed thread pool
  val collections = Seq.fill(numberThreads) {
    new Callable[T]() {
      def call = body
    }
  }
  val futures = javaExecutor.invokeAll(collections.asJavaCollection) // run pool, first convert Seq to java.util.Collection
  // Here you have to be sure, that all task run
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  concurrent.Future(javaExecutor.shutdown()) // shutdown in new thread
  futures // return java futures !!!
}

val futures = execInParallel(9, Thread.currentThread.getName)
println("Hurray")
futures.asScala.foreach(x => println(x.get))
```

Comment: code looks great, but my goal here is to _learn_, not just to get the code.  Can you explain what you did and how it works?

Comment: Check java.util.concurrent package, or RxJava (RxScala is wrapper) - there you will find all what you need.

Comment: Is that a typo? Should "asJavaColRxScalalection" be "asJavaCollection"

Comment: This is a java solution not a scala one.

Comment: Scala wraps java.util.concurrent. Scala is run on jvm. If you want to use low level api - you has to use java api.

Comment: Great code.  Is there a way to make it return the main thread, instead of locking the main thread until it finishes?

Comment: Now it is not blocking. `concurrent.Future` creates new thread.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
 (1 to 10).toList.par.foreach(myBatchFunction)
```

It will invoke myBatchFunction 10 times, allowing Scala to determine when to do them in parallel.

Comment: Not sure it will create 10 threads, it may be related to the number of cores